# Bastion unexpectedly exits when I move my cursor

Tags: intel-graphics, intel, cursor

I downloaded the Humble Indie Bundle V, mostly because my friend told me about how great Bastion was. When I first installed it, I was getting the seemingly common "black screen" error that most people got (fixed that half with this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11992661). But I also have an error where every time I move my cursor, in any direction, any amount, the game closes instantly. I can use the keyboard no problem, but without fail, every time I move my mouse, it crashes.

Does anyone know what might be causing this? Has anyone encountered anything like this before? I am worried it may be a hardware issue, but hoping someone might be able to help me out.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on a Dell Studio 1558. Graphics card is the stock Intel graphics card, running on 4 GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article in portuguese](http://www.ubuntubrsc.com/resolvendo-problemas-humble-bundle-v-para-linux.html#.T9J1z9OYNok) has the codes to solve most of the port errors of the Humble Indie Bundle V. If you don't understand it, just ask me and I'll try to provide a translated version of it.

Comment: If you are using the Firefox browser, you can install an addon called "Translate This! v1.8" and then use it to translate the Portuguese into something a little more readable.